# Stop python mode jumping to function definition?

Tags: python

I recently installed python-mode (via `package-list-packages`). Since then, whenever I put my cursor by a function I've defined, it jumps to it, and if I put my cursor by a builtin function or operator (or some installed third party thing, like a module name), it opens `python-help`.

I would like to stop this happening. Any ideas on how to stop this, or even really what might be doing this if it's not python-mode would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you see the same thing with the builtin python-mode (which should generally give you pretty much the same featureset)?

Comment: @Stefan I do not

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, Emacs comes with a `python-mode` by default, that comes from a file called `python.el`. There is also a package available on MELPA called `python-mode`, which will override the built-in `python-mode`.

When I installed the MELPA `python-mode` and tried to use it, various sorts of oddness happened -- it kind of looked like it was trying to execute the code as I was typing it, maybe? It was similar to what you describe.

I would try deleting the `python-mode` package you installed, restart Emacs, and open up a Python script and see if Emacs doesn't just do the right thing all by itself, without needing to install anything.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (kill-local-variable 'eldoc-documentation-function)))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: While I am not sure why this works, this copy-pasting this answer into my .emacs file solved the problem :) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen also when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), and you just load the python-mode package? If not, bisect your init file to find the problem. If yes, check the doc or code of that package for a way out.